# MSM and Custom Bootstrap Config

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm running on my own "multi environment config" bootstrap file (https://github.com/madebymayo/ExpressionEngine-Environment-Config), but i've never used it with a site running on MSM (Multi Site Manager)

At first I ran in to the problem with the whole site not showing up, and giving me a 500 error. But I realised I hadn't added this:

```
$config['multiple_sites_enabled'] = "y";
```

So after adding this in, the site started to show this:

```
Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found
```

I've double checked my admin.php and index.php files are in each of my MSM folders.

Am I missing some sort of config hook to make my own config file work with a MSM site?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing this line in my config file:

> $config['site_name'] = "";

Fixed this issue.

Comment: Happened to me as well. general rule of thumb is that site_name and site_url go in the index.php of the various sites and must be removed from config.php.

Comment: Just found out recently that, apparently, site_url (main site) has to be in config.php for site duplication to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if switching URI PROTOCOL in the config.php from 'AUTO' to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

works for you. It's worked for me before.

Comment: This didn't work - it still gives me the "No Preferences Found" error...